SQL function Error : near "FROM": syntax error
IDK what is wrong but its not working? Could someone help me on this? I am trying to get an output with diagnosis and if patient id is even then Yes and No otherwise.

Error : near "FROM": syntax error

SELECT diagnosis,
CASE WHEN patient_id % 2 = 0 Then 
    'Yes'
ELSE 
    'No' 
END as has_insurance,
FROM admissions 
;

Correct answer and what could be wrong?

has_insurance, <-- delete the dangling comma here

It is an Syntax Error.Try removing last comma before FROM.
SELECT diagnosis,
CASE WHEN patient_id % 2 = 0 Then 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as has_insurance
FROM admissions ;

